# Android. Starting activity from Optionsmenu

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreateoptionsmenu

I meet a problem starting the activity from optionmenu. I need to go to Logout activity when Logout is pressed. But nothing happens..
Here is my code:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle menuinstance) {
    super.onCreate(menuinstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

}
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override 

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Logout:
            startActivity(new Intent("com.project.myAndroid.Logout"));
            break;}
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please write this :

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Logout:
startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Logout.class));
break;}
return true;
```

instead of :

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Logout:
startActivity(new Intent("com.project.myAndroid.Logout"));
break;}
return true;
```

Comment: The constructor Intent(MenuActivity, String) is undefined

Comment: OK see my edit now, just `"com.project.myAndroid.Logout"` replaced with `Logout.class`, try now

Comment: No eror, but same problem. when i press logout in my android, optionsmenu dissapear ,but im still in savme activity

Comment: Please can you send me code of `MenuActivity.java` if??

Comment: I have tried, code works for me please double check where you are making mistake, I have done see here http://pastebin.com/MhCX5B4f

Comment: Can you send me the complete source code of your App?

Comment: Man I can not find any bug, because it works here on my side, but I have sent a working Demo `Test-Drive` that please...

Comment: Is there any other way to create menu, and start activities if menu item is pressed ?

Comment: OK no pleblem you can run that, `Goto-Project Properties` select `Android` then select Android version you have installed on your Drive.

Comment: You are on right way but I don't know why your code does not work?

Comment: really thanks. I cant check if the code wrks on my project at the moment. Tomorow i will :)